# Python3 evenly distribute a number between 0 to 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need a function that can calculate a given number evenly between 0 to 10 into three decimal places like the example shown below.

```
# ask user to input an int
value = int(iinput('Enter an number: ))

# if the user enters 5
Enter a number: 5
# the result will be
0.000 2.500 5.000 7.500 10.000
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
def f(num):
    factor = 10/(num-1)
    return [i*factor for i in range(num)]

f(5) # [0.0, 2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0]
```

once you have the list, format and print it however you like.

Comment: It works i just need to tweak for the three decimal places. Thanks a lot

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Providing ready answers to posts that do not demonstrate any effort is frown upon on SO.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np    
np.linspace(0, 10, value)
```

Comment: Thaks a lot. my numpy doesn't seem to work i will have to work on that